# How to hide rows from table view when is selected

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I want to hide the row when I selected that
For example if I select row "uno", that row goes to other view controller to take a photo and when the user take a photo, the app returns to the view controller where there is the table view but I want to hide the row selected

I used this but it doesn´t work

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.row == 0{
        return 0
    }


       return tableView.rowHeight


}
```

[table view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xa1P0.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to a remove a row, look at your datasource.  If you are populating this table view from an array, just remove the item at the selected index from the array in `didSelectRowAt` and call `tableView.reloadData()`

Comment: but the function `didSelectItemAt` is it for colletion view, isn´t  it ? I did my menu with a table view

Comment: @JesusLoaizaHerrera Edited.  DidSelectRowAt for tableViews

Comment: This is correct. Your tableView and data source should be in sync